# Post thumbnails won't change size

Tags: wordpress

I'm listing a lot of products on one page, and untill recently I used dimensions 390px*238px. Now I have to change the dimesions to something else, I updated `get_the_post_thumbnail` method with new parameters, page reloads and shows everything like I wanted it to be.

But, on next refresh, everything goes back as it were. When I inspect the elements, image that is displayed indeed has class `attachment-390x501`, but it's `width`, `height` and src attributes show 390, 238 and `path/to/website/uploads/2012/11/Profile_IS_20180-390x238.jpg`.

Is there a way to change my thumbnail dimensions? Here's the code I use currently:

```
<?php 
     // previous dimensions were 390x238
     echo get_the_post_thumbnail($product->ID, array(390,501)); 
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the size of the thumbnails by adding a line to your functions.php file and then display the new image size.

Add this to functions.php, you can change the numbers if you need to as that is the dimensions.  Also, you can repeat this line as many times as you'd like to set different size thumbnails, just change `new_custom_size` to a unique name for each new size.

`add_image_size( 'new_custom_size', 390, 501, true );`

Then display your featured image with this:

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('new_custom_size'); ?>`

You will need to regenerate your thumbnails once you set the size in the functions.php file and before you display it on the page/post.  I highly recommend the Renegerate Thumbnails plugin for this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Great answer, thanks. But now, my images show in correct sizes with new image size class (it's `attachment-new_custom_size` in this case). Is this permanent, or I need to regenerate thumbs anyway?

Comment: If you're only applying a CSS class to the images to change their size it is not creating new thumbnails with those specific dimensions.  If you are using `get_the_post_thumbnail($id, array(100,100) );` then they should be the size that you specify.  Your best bet and what I'd still recommend is using the information from my answer.  This will ensure that your images display in the correct size as there is a WordPress generated thumbnail for each image that has those exact dimensions.

Answer (score -1):

use [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) and [rebuild thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)

Comment: This is a useless answer.  You need to clarify how this works and include some code to properly answer this question.  Posting two links does nothing.